# how to delete the record from the join table in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

forum member

I need one help from you all. I am having two POJO model with one to many relationship.
**my project pojo is below**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "project")
public class Project implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer projectid;
    private Date enddate;
    private String projectdesc;
    private String projectname;
    private String projecttitle;
    private Date startdate;
    private Set<Task> tasks = new HashSet<Task>(0);

    public Project() {
    }

    public Project (Integer id,String projectname, String projecttitle, String projectdesc, Date startdate, Date enddate) {
        this.projectid = id;
        this.enddate = enddate;
        this.projectdesc = projectdesc;
        this.projectname = projectname;
        this.projecttitle = projecttitle;
        this.startdate = startdate;
    }

    public Project(Date enddate, String projectdesc, String projectname,
            String projecttitle, Date startdate, Set<Task> tasks) {
        this.enddate = enddate;
        this.projectdesc = projectdesc;
        this.projectname = projectname;
        this.projecttitle = projecttitle;
        this.startdate = startdate;
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "projectid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getProjectid() {
        return projectid;
    }

    public void setProjectid(Integer projectid) {
        this.projectid = projectid;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "enddate", length = 19)
    public Date getEnddate() {
        return enddate;
    }

    public void setEnddate(Date enddate) {
        this.enddate = enddate;
    }

    @Column(name = "projectdesc")
    public String getProjectdesc() {
        return projectdesc;
    }

    public void setProjectdesc(String projectdesc) {
        this.projectdesc = projectdesc;
    }

    @Column(name = "projectname")
    public String getProjectname() {
        return projectname;
    }

    public void setProjectname(String projectname) {
        this.projectname = projectname;
    }

    @Column(name = "projecttitle")
    public String getProjecttitle() {
        return projecttitle;
    }

    public void setProjecttitle(String projecttitle) {
        this.projecttitle = projecttitle;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "startdate", length = 19)
    public Date getStartdate() {
        return startdate;
    }

    public void setStartdate(Date startdate) {
        this.startdate = startdate;
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch =FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "project_task", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "projectid") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "taskid") })
    public Set<Task> getTasks() {
        return tasks;
    }

    public void setTasks(Set<Task> tasks) {
        this.tasks = tasks;
    }


}
```

**and my task pojo is**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "task")
public class Task implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer taskid;
    private Integer depth;
    private Double duration;
    private String durationunit;
    private Date enddate;
    private Integer parentid;
    private Integer percentdone;
    private Integer priority;
    private Date startdate;
    private Integer taskindex;
    private String taskname;

    public Task() {
    }

    public Task(Integer depth, Double duration, String durationunit,
            Date enddate, Integer parentid, Integer percentdone,
            Integer priority, Date startdate, Integer taskindex,
            String taskname) {
        this.depth = depth;
        this.duration = duration;
        this.durationunit = durationunit;
        this.enddate = enddate;
        this.parentid = parentid;
        this.percentdone = percentdone;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.startdate = startdate;
        this.taskindex = taskindex;
        this.taskname = taskname;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "taskid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getTaskid() {
        return taskid;
    }

    public void setTaskid(Integer taskid) {
        this.taskid = taskid;
    }

    @Column(name = "depth")
    public Integer getDepth() {
        return depth;
    }

    public void setDepth(Integer depth) {
        this.depth = depth;
    }

    @Column(name = "duration", precision = 22, scale = 0)
    public Double getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }

    public void setDuration(Double duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    @Column(name = "durationunit")
    public String getDurationunit() {
        return durationunit;
    }

    public void setDurationunit(String durationunit) {
        this.durationunit = durationunit;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "enddate", length = 19)
    public Date getEnddate() {
        return enddate;
    }

    public void setEnddate(Date enddate) {
        this.enddate = enddate;
    }

    @Column(name = "parentid")
    public Integer getParentid() {
        return parentid;
    }

    public void setParentid(Integer parentid) {
        this.parentid = parentid;
    }

    @Column(name = "percentdone")   
    public Integer getPercentdone() {
        return percentdone;
    }

    public void setPercentdone(Integer percentdone) {
        this.percentdone = percentdone;
    }

    @Column(name = "priority")
    public Integer getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(Integer priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "startdate", length = 19)
    public Date getStartdate() {
        return startdate;
    }

    public void setStartdate(Date startdate) {
        this.startdate = startdate;
    }

    @Column(name = "taskindex")
    public Integer getTaskindex() {
        return taskindex;
    }

    public void setTaskindex(Integer taskindex) {
        this.taskindex = taskindex;
    }

    @Column(name = "taskname")
    public String getTaskname() {
        return taskname;
    }

    public void setTaskname(String taskname) {
        this.taskname = taskname;
    }


}
```

**the project pojo is associated with task as one-to-many relationship**. Now I want to delete one task based on the id I am passing,
 but the problem is that I am not able to delete the foreign key of the join table project_task.

I tried below code to delete the project_task first

```
Session session = this.hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("delete from project_task where taskid="+id);
        query.executeUpdate();
```

and then tried to delete the task with below code

```
Object record = hibernateTemplate.load(Task.class, id);
hibernateTemplate.delete(record);
```

but don't know why delete is not happening here. Any one having idea what I am doing wrong in my code **which doesn't allow the delete to be happened**

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you are using a join table for a one-to-many relationship, instead of a foreign key on the Task side?

Comment: I just want my database to be clean. my project_task table will manage all the relationship between the project and task. One project Id associated with many tasks Id in project_task table.  Everything is working correctly now I just stuck down when I want to delete the tasks. Any solution you having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try breaking the association first:

```
Task record = hibernateTemplate.load(Task.class, id);
Project project = hibernateTemplate.load(Project.class, projectId);
project.getTasks().remove(record);
hibernateTemplate.update(project);
hibernateTemplate.delete(record);
```

If you don't have the project id available, you might want to create an inverse ManyToOne relationship inside task.

Comment: I tried your solution but my console gives me error **ERROR org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException - could not initialize proxy - no Session** so what's the problem now ?? any idea why the error is coming

Comment: That's weird, because the tasks collection is eager loaded. Which statement throws it? That might be the problem with the hibernate template, as far as I remember each call is it's own session. Can you switch to a normal hibernate session (e.g. without hibernate template)?

Comment: thanks for your reply. After changing the hibernate template to normal hibernate session everything starts working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should change the task set in Project and then try to remove the task...

I think you can use cascade.type All (on setTasks) too...

You have to remove from task Set you have the task you want to remove... and update the Entity

Comment: I actually had implemented the **@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch =FetchType.EAGER)** in my project Pojo. I just want to delete my task and all its associated foreign key from project_task table any solution you having ?

Comment: Please give us what error you have... if you don't have any error, please check your database and not code :) hibernate has some cache stuff..

Comment: Hibernate is not giving me error namde **Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`primavera`.`project_task`, CONSTRAINT `FK3800AAEBACB7568D` FOREIGN KEY (`taskid`) REFERENCES `task` (`taskid`))** as the join table project_task has taskid in it the delete procedure fails to delete the task. So how can I delete the join table project_task containing taskid

Comment: what happens if you just set like this:
`tasks.setTasks(---set without that task---);`
Isn't it working?

Comment: Alex you are getting me wrong I want to delete Task object from the join table project_task which is created. If I delete the task based on the Id I get the above error. So is there any better way I can delete the task successfully and also my join table project_task's taskid gets deleted. ?

Comment: yes.. I understood this. but If you remove the task from that set, JPA (hibernate) will automatically unlink the connection between task and project... so.. what remains left is to remove the task... You are using hibernate to avoid sql...

Comment: so how do I remove the task after deleting the task ??